# Simple timestamping filter in C

Tags: c, datetime, logging, interval

I wrote a simple timestamping filter that prepends each line with the UNIX timestamp in nanosecond precision as returned by clock_gettime, as well as the difference to the previous timestamp.

```bash
for i in {01..15}; do printf '%s\n' "input $i"; sleep 0."$i"; done | ./timestamper

  BEGIN CLOCK_REALTIME. No monotonicity guaranteed.
  1568821823.653421652 ▒       0.00 ▒ input 01
  1568821823.664177279 ▒      10.76 ▒ input 02
  1568821823.688901171 ▒      24.72 ▒ input 03
  1568821823.720398267 ▒      31.50 ▒ input 04
  1568821823.761946412 ▒      41.55 ▒ input 05
  1568821823.813324331 ▒      51.38 ▒ input 06
  1568821823.874711521 ▒      61.39 ▒ input 07
  1568821823.946274595 ▒      71.56 ▒ input 08
  1568821824.027733690 ▒      81.46 ▒ input 09
  1568821824.119107230 ▒      91.37 ▒ input 10
  1568821824.220571393 ▒     101.46 ▒ input 11
  1568821824.331862345 ▒     111.29 ▒ input 12
  1568821824.453478061 ▒     121.62 ▒ input 13
  1568821824.584820550 ▒     131.34 ▒ input 14
  1568821824.726266816 ▒     141.45 ▒ input 15
  END CLOCK_REALTIME
```

I mainly wrote this program because the shell code

```bash
while IFS=  read -r line
do
    printf '%s | %s\n' "$(date -u '+%F %T.%4N')" "$line"
done
```

forks a "date" process for every line, which is about 800 times slower than the C program, on some unspecified amd64 system at uni.

A quick test:

```bash
$ time cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[[:print:]]' | tr 'A' '\n' | head -n 10000000 > /dev/null
real    0m23.280s

$ time cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[[:print:]]' | tr 'A' '\n' | head -n 10000000 | ./timestamper > /dev/null
real    0m26.624s
```

which makes for an overhead of about 14 per cent, on some unspecified amd64 system at uni.

In this review, I'd like to focus on code quality and readability while not completely forgetting performance. In particular,

- Should I do away with the #defines and use functions instead?
- Any more error conditions to check for?

More questions (less important today):

- Is there a nice way of handling really long lines, short of splitting and joining them by hand? I don't want to allocate tons of memory, even if it has to be done only once.
- Any suggestions on the column separator? (Doing `... | ./timestamper | tr $'\x1a' '|'` is easy enough, though.) TAB does not work because "git status" output uses it, which came as a surprise. I would like to be able to pass anything through the filter that could reasonably be produced by verbose programs. I'm thinking of SSH clients and the like.
- I took the liberty to replace CR with LF because I do not want to lose information. Any thoughts on that?
- What about locale issues? Should I worry about them at all or just pass through whatever comes in?

Oh, and is there a magic pill that forces me to write comments consistently in English?

So, finally, here is the code:

```
/*

  NAME

       timestamper - timestamp and kill-carriage-return


  SYNOPSIS

       ./timestamper


  DESCRIPTION

       Ersetzt in jeder über die Standardeingabe eingelesenen Zeile,
       nachdem die Dauer seit Eintreffen der vorhergehenden Zeile
       festgehalten wurde, das Wagenrücklaufzeichen (ASCII 13 = 0x0D)
       durch ein Neue-Zeile-Zeichen (ASCII 10 = 0x0A) und schreibt den
       Zeitstempel des Eintreffens und die Dauer, gefolgt von
       der veränderten Zeile, auf die Standardausgabe. Als
       Trennzeichen wird der "substitute character" (ASCII 26 = 0x1A)
       genutzt, damit alle gewöhnlichen druckbaren Zeichen die
       Prozedur unbeschadet überstehen.

       nach https://stackoverflow.com/a/12722972
       2019-09-14

       Dieser Code wurde bisher unter Debian GNU/Linux 9 und unter
       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS getestet.


  OPTIONS, ARGUMENTS, PARAMETERS

       Nichts von alledem.


  EXIT STATUS

       0 bei erfolgreicher Ausführung,
       1 bei Fehler.

       Ein Fehler liegt insbesondere dann vor, wenn

       - von der Standardeingabe nicht gelesen werden kann;
       - auf die Standardausgabe nicht geschrieben werden kann;
       - das Abfragen der Uhrzeit fehlschlägt.


  HOW TO COMPILE

       Für schnelle Tests kann man

           gcc timestamper.c -o timestamper

       nutzen. Man kann aber auch

           gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Wfatal-errors -pedantic -Os timestamper.c -o timestamper

       versuchen. 


  WHAT THE FUCK?

       Die Existenzberechtigung dieses Programms ergibt sich aus der
       Tatsache, dass jeder "date"-Aufruf in der Shell einen neuen
       Prozess startet, was, wenn es einmal pro gelesener Zeile
       passiert, etwas viel ist. Details sind am Ende dieser Datei
       nachzulesen.


  BUGS

       Bisher werden von jeder Zeile, die 10000 oder mehr Zeichen
       enthält, nur die ersten 9999 Zeichen verarbeitet.


  COPYRIGHT

       (c) Thure Dührsen, 2019-09-15...18

       Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to anyone
       obtaining a copy of this software and the accompanying
       documentation files, to do WHATEVER THEY WANT, subject to the
       following conditions:

       (a) Read and understand the file 'license.txt' in the project
           repository's root directory.

       (b) Acknowledge that this software draws substantially from
           StackOverflow posts, and that any public releases must
           comply with the terms laid out in the Creative Commons
           Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International Public License,

             https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode

*/


#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L  /* man 2 clock_getres */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void usage(void) {
  fprintf (stderr, "%s\n",
           "\n\
        Usage: \n\
\n\
          timestamper\n\
\n\
        No options, no arguments.\n"

  );  
}


#define sep ((char)0x1A) /* ASCII substitute character */


/* Speed is everything. No functions. Just #defines. */

#define PROCESSLINE                                              \
                                                                 \
  /* search for first '\n' and change it to \0 */                \
  /* nach https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221 */                \
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;                                   \
                                                                 \
  /* Logdateien sind ohne Wagenrücklauf einfacher zu lesen */    \
  for (i = 0; (b = buf[i]) != 0; i++) {                          \
    if (b == '\r') {buf[i] = '\n';}                              \
  } /************************************************************/



#define READCLOCK(i)                                             \
                                                                 \
  /* CLOCK_MONOTONIC has an unspecified starting point */        \
  /* CLOCK_REALTIME starts on 1970-01-01 */                      \
                                                                 \
  r = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t##i);                      \
                                                                 \
  if (r != 0) {                                                  \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Cannot read clock");                \
    exit(1);                                                     \
  } /************************************************************/


#define WRITELINE(duration, i)                                   \
                                                                 \
  r = printf ("%010ld.%09ld %c %10.2f %c %s\n",                  \
                                                                 \
       /* tv_sec ist vom Typ time_t */                           \
       (long int) t##i.tv_sec,                                   \
       /* time_t ist auf amd64-Rechnern ein Synonym für long int,
          was bei anderen Architekturen nicht der Fall sein muss.
          Der Cast nach long int ist daher vermutlich nötig. */  \
                                                                 \
       /* tv_nsec ist ein long int */                            \
       t##i.tv_nsec,                                             \
                                                                 \
       sep,                                                      \
                                                                 \
       duration,                                                 \
                                                                 \
       sep,                                                      \
                                                                 \
       buf);                                                     \
                                                                 \
  if (r < 0) {                                                   \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n" ,"Cannot write to stdout");           \
    exit(1);                                                     \
  }                                                              \
                                                                 \
  if (r > bufsize * 0.95) {                                      \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",                                      \
    "That's some jolly long lines you have there...");           \
  } /************************************************************/



int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  if (argc != 1 || argv[1] != NULL) {
    /* suppress compiler warnings about argc and argv */
    usage();
    exit(1);
  }

  struct timespec t1, t2;

  const int bufsize = 10000;

  char buf[bufsize];
  int i;
  int b; /* ein einzelnes Zeichen */

  int r; /* Rückgabewert von clock_gettime, printf */

  void* rp; /* Rückgabewert von fgets */

  long int d;  /* Differenz zweier Zeitstempel */
  double   df; /* wie oben, aber Millisekunden */

  printf("%s\n","BEGIN CLOCK_REALTIME. No monotonicity guaranteed.");

  rp = fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin);

  if (rp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n" ,"Nothing on stdin");
    exit(1);
  }

  PROCESSLINE;
  READCLOCK(1);

  /* Gib 0 als Zeitdifferenz sowie die Zeile aus */

  WRITELINE((double)0, 1);

  /* Solange noch Zeilen über stdin eingelesen werden können... */

  while (fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin) != NULL) {

    PROCESSLINE;
    READCLOCK(2);

    /* Bilde Differenz */

    d = ((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec)*1000000000L
         +t2.tv_nsec) - t1.tv_nsec;

    df = d / 1000000.0;

    /* Rette vorigen Zeitstempel: setze t1 := t2 */

    t1 = t2;

    /* Gib Differenz und eingelesene Zeile
       auf der Standardausgabe aus */

    WRITELINE(df, 2);
  }

  printf("%s\n","END CLOCK_REALTIME");

  return 0;
}

/*
    performance tests omitted here,
    see description in the question
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I must apologies that my German understanding isn't fluent enough to read all your comments.

I think your intuition is right that you ought to be using functions rather than preprocessor macros - the latter are just too fragile, and anyway, good compilers are able to inline functions.  I would recommend `-O3 -march=native` in your GCC flags if speed is your main concern.

The code builds mostly clean, and gives Valgrind no cause to grumble - well done!

---

A better way to run your tests might be to time only the timestamper itself:

```sh
</dev/urandom tr -dc '[[:print:]]' | tr 'A' '\n' | head -n10000000 \
    | time ./timestamper >/dev/null
```

This saves you having to do a subtraction.  Note that overhead "percentage" is somewhat meaningless here, as we could make the input stream arbitrarily complex and reduce the percentage to any figure we want!

I've also eliminated the unnecessary `cat`, even though this isn't a [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) review.

---

There's a bug, which is easily demonstrated: we always print a time offset of zero for the first line, but it would be more useful to print the time since the program was started.  I'd be happy to go with a compromise, and just use the time that `main()` is entered.

---

I'm not convinced of the need for the buffer (and certainly not of the need to remove the final newline, only to add one when we print), as we can work on a character by character basis, and lean on the buffering inside `<stdio.h>`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    bool is_first = true;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &last_time)) {
        perror("Cannot read clock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (is_first) {
            print_time_prefix();
            is_first = false;
        }
        putchar(c);
        if (c == '\n') {
            is_first = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little slower (8.4 seconds, compared with 5.8 seconds for the original), but much easier to work with.

---

My take on the separator is that control characters are a poor choice for printing; I'd much rather see tabs than `^Z` in the output.  Most tools that read tab-separated values can be told how many fields to use.

---

My full program uses no macros, and a single global variable:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L  /* man 2 clock_getres */

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec last_time;

static void print_time_prefix(void)
{
    struct timespec now;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now)) {
        perror("Cannot read clock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double interval = now.tv_sec - last_time.tv_sec
        + .000000001 * (now.tv_nsec - last_time.tv_nsec);

    printf("%010ld"  "." "%09ld"   "\t"  "%10.2f"  "\t",
           now.tv_sec,    now.tv_nsec,    interval);

    last_time = now;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &last_time)) {
        perror("Cannot read clock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bool is_first = true;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (is_first) {
            print_time_prefix();
            is_first = false;
        }
        putchar(c);
        if (c == '\n') {
            is_first = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Some things of note:

- I use the predefined `EXIT_FAILURE` macro as exit status in the error case.
- Unless we're stuck in the 20th century, we don't need to declare all the variables at the beginning of their scope.
- `clock_gettime()` sets `errno` on failure, so use `perror()` to report that.
- I wrote the format string as multiple concatenated segments to help it line up with the arguments, and separate the literal parts from the conversions.

Things not addressed in my version:

- We might consider keeping the interval as a pair of integral values (as with the timestamps), rather than creating and printing a floating-point value.
- We ought to print using the user's expected decimal separator (e.g. `,`), instead of hard-coded `.` in the format string.  I've not done this myself, but I believe what we need to do is

  1. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` early on, as usual for a locale-aware program.
  2. Obtain the formatting rules using `localeconv()`.
  3. Examine the `decimal_point` member of the resulting `lconv` object.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions! Reading input on a char by char basis is the sort of thing I tend to miss when writing the algorithm on paper without a computer in front of me :) Also, while `if (clock_gettime(...)) {perror(...)}` is correct, it reads like `if you can query the clock, throw an error`. But that's just me, I guess ;)

Comment: Well, you can throw in a `!= 0` if that makes it read easier for you (yes, I also find it reads that way, but years of C have inured me to the different error returns of library calls!).  The `perror()` call is the real point here.

Comment: @Thure, I've updated with some handwaving to answer your specific question about locale handling.  I hope that's helpful.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. BTW what compiler do you use, as you say the code builds mostly clean? Using `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Wfatal-errors -pedantic -Os timestamper.c -o timestamper` gives no output on my machine. I'm using gcc 6.3.0 on Debian 9.

Comment: I also had ` -Warray-bounds  -Wstrict-prototypes    -Wconversion   -Wwrite-strings` (with GCC 9.2.1).  There's a conversion warning when promoting the time values to `double`, but I believe the code is fine for the values that could actually be present, on any actual Unix or Linux platform.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I do away with the #defines and use functions instead?

Probably.

> Speed is everything. No functions. Just #defines.

Are you so sure? Have you tested the speed of your application when using regular functions? Optimizing C compilers are pretty good. They'll be able to inline away the functions that you write. Defaulting to writing `#define` macros based on the belief that it will make things faster is classic premature optimization. The macros might even *be* faster, but you haven't proven so, and they aren't the first thing you should reach for. Instead, you should first make your program correct; then you should profile your application to find bottlenecks. It's going to be unlikely that you'll find a bottleneck caused by writing functions, and using macros comes at a heavy cost of legibility and maintainability.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't, and I took my numerical analysis instructor's word in good faith. But it's the weekend now, so I'll write a little test harness for good measure.